# Loud Vibrating Noise coming from Walls and Ceiling

Tags: walls, ceiling, vibration

Watch youtube video to hear noise: https://www.youtube.com/shorts/7oyls5YQ0Mo
My issue:

- Loud vibrating sound coming from ceiling and/or walls
- It lasts about 30 seconds
- It sounds like (and is almost as loud as) a washing machine on spin cycle
- It happens once or twice a day, different times of the day
- It can happen in the middle of the night, when everyone is sleeping and when nothing is running at the time, including AC, running water, toilet flushing, dish washer etc
- The room I hear the noise the loudest (the room in the video) is on the first floor. It shares a wall with the garage where the electric hot water heater is
- I don't feel any vibrations from the hot water heater pipes and the noise is not as loud in the garage

Do you have any idea of the source of the noise?

Comment: Sounds almost like a helicopter flying over head.  Have you gone outside to check on the noise?

Comment: Are you in a detached house with no chance this could simply be a neighbour choosing to do their washing at strange times?

Comment: @crip659  gotta agree, really sounds like a helicopter.  To the OP are you near an airport or military base?

Comment: @Tetsujin,  I'm in a single family home.

Comment: @crip659,  next time I'll run outside to see, but I'm confident that the source is inside.

Comment: did you talk to the neighbor

Comment: @Ruskes I'm confident it's coming from inside the house.  But next time I'll run outside to make sure it's not originating from out there.  It only lasts for 30 seconds or so, so it's hard to troubleshoot.  The sound is much louder and clearing in person, it sounds like it's coming from in the ceiling.

Comment: do not know where you live, but any trains, subways

Comment: You'll need to take a peek in the attic and see what mechanical devices might be up there. Maybe triggered by a timer or sensor to do who knows what?  Attic air circ, sensor driven by heat or humidity? Since it's random, if there is a device up there, it's almost certainly triggered by a sensor.   Just a thought, you'll find it.

Comment: Any chance you have a basement sump pump that might be trying to pump water out and it's making noise?  Usually they're pretty quiet, but if imbalanced, could make noise.  Does it start and stop suddenly, or fade louder and then get softer?  That would likely eliminate a helicopter if it starts and stops suddenly.  Also, could be some sort of air compressor that keeps pressure up for some sort of device or air storage tank?

Comment: Thanks @Milwrdfan.  I don't have a basement or sump pump.   It starts pretty suddenly, not sure if it fades away though.  I'm too busy running around trying to find the source to take notice.  I will next time.    I don't have an air compressor. 
I took a look in the attic and didn't find anything up there that would start on its own or that would make that particular noise.

Comment: A few had suggested a helicopter.  The reason why I ruled out a helicopters is that when the noise starts I run to the second floor thinking it would be louder but it's actually softer.  Perhaps this particular room has some odd acoustics that is magnifying the outside sound.  Next time it happens i'll rush outside.

Comment: that sounds like a compressor ... could also be related to the water pipe

Comment: @jsotola The ac unit is right outside, I'll make sure to check it next time.

Comment: It is definitely a compressor.  If you have discovered what it is, then please post an answer here.

Comment: Except you say no water was flowing this sounds rather like what happened to us when city water pressure went up.  Nothing in the house could trigger it but the one high-flow irrigation line could--even though no water was flowing in the noisy pipe when that happened.  Installed a pressure regulator (our house was built a few years before code mandated them) and the problem went away.

Comment: I still haven’t found the issue.  The sound is intermittent and since the post it happened several more times then stopped for the last couple of months.  My latest theory is that it’s the water heater.  I’ve read that a water heater could produce similar noises when there is a lot of settlement at the bottom.  Perhaps I’m not hearing the noise now because the water heater isn’t working so hard because the weather has been hotter and the solar panel that is dedicated to the water heater has been doing the work.  I’m going to wait to see if it starts back up when the weather gets cooler

Answer (score 1):

So we had the same thing and it turned out to be a bad check valve on our water meter that our town installed. They replaced it today and no more sporadic helicopter sounds. Whew!